# Use SHAP values for Pytorch Residual network

Tags: python, pytorch, shap, deep-residual-networks

When I use SHAP to explain my neural networks, I encountered the following warning. How can I set it to not display this warning?

```
Warning: unrecognized nn.Module: Flatten
Warning: unrecognized nn.Module: Identity
```

I tried using the 'warnings' package at the beginning and set it to warnings.filterwarnings("ignore"), but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.